# Davar Ha'avad on Chol HaMoed -- Loss coming later

Tags: halacha, money, time, chol-hamoed

It says in SA OC Siman 537 that one is allowed to do a malacha on chol hamoed if it's a "davar ha'aved". That is to say if the person doesn't do the malacha now it will come to a loss ("hefsed".)

Does this mean that if the person will not do the malacha now he will have an immediate loss. Or is it even if at a later time the person will experience a loss.

I'll give an example. A sofer is writing a Sefer Torah that must be completed by a certain date (by a yarhzeit.) If it's not completed by that day the person will have to pay back a "fine" to the one purchasing the Sefer Torah (an amount that will be a significant loss to the sofer.) The sofer made a schedule and came to the conclusion that he must work the few days of chol hamoed in order to complete the Sefer Torah on time. This is a situation that the person will come to a potential loss if they don't work on Chol HaMoed, however it won't be immediate.

Is this still considered a davar ha'avad?